# Como somar valores no meio de um foreach?

Tags: php, laravel, php-7

Eu tenho um `foreach` que monta várias tabelas, porém tem um `td` na minha tabela que ele é a soma de outros `td`.

Tentei fazer com *JavaScript* e montar algumas lógicas no *PHP*, mas sem sucesso.

**O campo é o ultimo do `tbody`, o que tem o *data-total***

```
@foreach($lancamentos as $lancamento)
@if($lancamento['lojas']['id'] != $id_anterior)
<?php  
    $id_anterior = $lancamento['lojas']['id'];
?> 
<table class="table table-sm table-striped table-bordered" id="{{$lancamento['lojas']['id']}}">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="7" style="text-align: center;"><b>Loja:</b> {{$lancamento['lojas']['nome']}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Boleta</td>
            <td>Romaneio</td>
            <td>Cliente</td>
            <td>Data da Compra</td>
            <td>Data de Vencimento</td>
            <td>Valor</td>
            <td>Valor a receber</td>
            <td>total</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    @endif

        <tr>
            <td>{{$lancamento['boleta']}}</td>
            <td>{{$lancamento['romaneio']}}</td>
            <td>{{$lancamento['cliente']}}</td>
            <td>{{$lancamento['data_compra']}}</td>
            <td>{{$lancamento['data_vencimento']}}</td>
            <td data-valor="{{$lancamento['lojas']['id']}}">R$ {{$lancamento['valor']}}</td>
            <td>R$ {{$lancamento['valor'] * ($lancamento['lojas']['comissao']/100)}}</td>   
            <td data-total="{{$lancamento['lojas']['id']}}">{{ $lancamento['valor'] }}</td>
        </tr>
        @if($lancamento['lojas']['id'] != $id_anterior)
    </tbody>
</table>
@endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: Explica melhor o que tu quer. O total seria a soma do "valor" e do "valor a receber"?

Comment: Não, o "total" seria a soma do "valor"

Answer (score 0):

Embora não recomendado, é possível utilizar as tags **@php** e **@endphp** dentro da sua view.

Poderia ser feito nesse caso algo como:

```
...
@php
  $total += $lancamento['valor'];
@endphp
<td data-total="{{$lancamento['lojas']['id']}}">{{ $total }}</td>
```

Lembrando de iniciar a variável **total** fora do seu loop igual a 0.